# Black opacity overlay making image increase in size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I have a small issue that is really bugging me. Whenever my images are hovered over, a black-overlay appears with an opacity. However, it makes the image grow in height. Please note, I am not referring to the transform, scale property. The actual image grows in height at the bottom of the image.

What is causing this?

```js
$('.home-img-block').find('img').each(function() {
  var imgClass = (this.width / this.height > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
  console.log(imgClass);
  $(this).addClass(imgClass);
});
```

```css
#home-img-block-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
}
#home-img-blocks {
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}
.home-img-block {
  width: 33.33%;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.home-img-block:hover .overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.home-img-block:after {
  content: attr(data-content);
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
.home-img-block:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.home-img-block img {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  /* IE 9 */
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  /* Opera */
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.home-img-block:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-transform: scale(1.25);
  /* IE 9 */
  -o-transform: scale(1.25);
  /* Opera */
  transform: scale(1.25);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 33.33%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.home-img-block img.wide {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.home-img-block img.tall {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home-img-blocks">
  <div data-content="FIND OUT MORE" class="home-img-block">
    <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test1.jpg">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div data-content="FIND OUT MORE" class="home-img-block">
    <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test2new.jpg">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div data-content="FIND OUT MORE" class="home-img-block">
    <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test3new.jpg">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Entirely irrelevant to your problem, but you can shorten that first snippet of jQuery (in which you add the class) to: `$('.home-img-block img').addClass(function () { return (this.width / this.height > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';  });` (But that's just a casual FYI and, as noted, irrelevant to your posted problem.) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Images have a crazy `display`. They are neither of the `block`, `inline-block`, or `inline`. Try giving `display: block` to image because of their `baseline` property.

```js
$('.home-img-block').find('img').each(function() {
  var imgClass = (this.width / this.height > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
  console.log(imgClass);
  $(this).addClass(imgClass);
});
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
#home-img-block-section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 900px;
}
#home-img-blocks {
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}
.home-img-block {
  width: 33.33%;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
.home-img-block:hover .overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.home-img-block:after {
  content: attr(data-content);
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 20px 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
.home-img-block:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.home-img-block img {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  /* IE 9 */
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  /* Opera */
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.home-img-block:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
  /* Firefox */
  -ms-transform: scale(1.25);
  /* IE 9 */
  -o-transform: scale(1.25);
  /* Opera */
  transform: scale(1.25);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 33.33%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.home-img-block img.wide {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.home-img-block img.tall {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="home-img-blocks">
  <div data-content="FIND OUT MORE" class="home-img-block">
    <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test1.jpg">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div data-content="FIND OUT MORE" class="home-img-block">
    <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test2new.jpg">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
  <div data-content="FIND OUT MORE" class="home-img-block">
    <img src="http://optimumwebdesigns.com/images/test3new.jpg">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nicely done; I hadn't realised the craziness of the `<img>` element's `display` type (or issues).

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Only thing different I did was applied it to this div `.home-img-block img` rather than all of the images. Thanks again!

Comment: I assumed that must have been the case; you have my sympathy for whatever time it took to discover the cause - though part of me wishes you'd asked that problem here (and self-answered it) to help out the community, and those of us that have never faced that problem :)

Comment: @Becky I should say that. Make sure you give it to only **those** images and not like how stupid I have given for all images for demo purpose. `:P`

Comment: @Becky Then all the images will be in their own line! `:P`

Comment: @DavidThomas Wow really? You would face it when you do the image linking in the "wrong" way. Who are now using images for linking? So now that's dead. And we all can jump in joy. CSS BG Image FTW! `:D`

Comment: Are images not `display:inline` by default, they only behave slightly differently as they are what is known as replaced elements

Comment: @Pete Nopes... Yes, that's right! `:P`